# MATLAB Slicing variable for PARFOR loops

Tags: matlab, for-loop, parallel-processing, parfor

I am trying to make the following loop parallel-friendly in `MATLAB` so that I can use `parfor`:

```
for ivert = 1 : nVerts
    b = obj.f( obj.neighIDs{ ivert } ); 
    x = obj.coeffMatrix{ ivert } \ b;
    obj.solution( ivert, : ) = x( 1 : 3 );
end
```

I tried to slice the variables according to MATLAB documentation posted [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variables.html):

```
parfor ivert = 1 : nVerts
    i = obj.neighIDs{ ivert };
    b = obj.f( i ); 
    A = obj.coeffMatrix{ ivert }
    x =  A \ b;
    obj.solution( ivert, : ) = x( 1 : 3 );
end
```

But MATLAB complains that:

```
Valid indices for `obj` are restricted in PARFOR loops.
```

Could someone give me some hints how to slice the variables in the above loop?

Comment: The indexing of `obj.f( i )` might be the problem. I guess Matlab is unhappy, that you calculate the index within the loop.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that MATLAB sees the first three lines of your `parfor` loop, and treats those as indexing expressions on `obj` - and it concludes that `obj` must be a `parfor` "broadcast" variable. The final line of your `parfor` loop is treated as an indexed assignment into `obj` (even though it looks like an indexed assignment into a field of `obj`). Because `obj` has been classified as "broadcast", you cannot assign into it. To fix this, I'd recommend doing something like this:

```
tmpSolution = zeros(nVerts, 3);
parfor ivert = 1:nVerts
    ... %# calculate 'x'
    tmpSolution(ivert, :) = x(1:3);
end
obj.solution = tmpSolution;
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you also recommend to define a function in order to calculate `x` and use it in the `parfor`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to resolve the issue by defining `tmpSolution`.

Comment: What is the remaining error? Did you replace the `obj.solution(...) = ...` line inside the `parfor` loop with my suggestion? I can't run your code, but making that change gets rid of the static analysis problem...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Yes, I did change that line. Are cells not `parfor` friendly?

Comment: Cell arrays are perfectly fine with `parfor`. Perhaps you could post updated code to demonstrate what you're trying and what the precise error you're getting is.

Comment: I was able to get the `parfor` to work but apparently there is no performance improvement. I ended up testing: `tmpSolution = cellfun( @(x, y) x \ obj.f( y ), obj.coeffMatrix, obj.neighIDs, 'UniformOutput', false );` to avoid looping through the cell elements but I don't see any improvement. Would GPU help?

Comment: `parfor` often doesn't help if MATLAB can intrinsically multithread your operations (and you're using only local workers). Sometimes GPU can be better - especially if you have large numeric vectorised operations. Note that `cellfun` doesn't really avoid the `for` loop, and in recent versions of MATLAB, `for` loops are not necessarily slow.