# Is MATLAB cellfun GPU-friendly

Tags: multithreading, matlab, parallel-processing, gpu

I have a loop in MATLAB which solves a linear system of equation. The total number of equations is about 500,000. Each system has 4 unknowns but the number of equations varies between 10 to 50. In addition, this system of equations needs to be solved over time (about 3000 timesteps)

```
for ivertex = 1 : nVertices
    b = obj.f( obj.neighIDs{ ivertex } ); 
    x = obj.coeffMatrix{ ivertex  } \ b;
    obj.solution( ivertex , : ) = x( 1 : 3 );
end
```

I [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37265344/1227860) to use `parfor` to accelerate this loop but I did not see any improvement. I also tried using `cellfun` to avoid looping through equations using MATLAB `for`:

```
tmpSolution = cellfun( ...
                     @(x, y) x \ obj.f( y ), ...
                     obj.coeffMatrix, ...
                     obj.neighIDs , ...
                     'UniformOutput', false );
```

But each timestep takes about 11 seconds (3000×11 = 9 hours). Is there a way to make this faster? Is this problem GPU friendly? My MATLAB version is 2013b in Windows 7 64 bit with 32 GB RAM.

Comment: MATLAB does not automatically use the GPU for anything. You need to convert your values to [`gpuArray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gpuarray.html) values in order to use the GPU.

Comment: On the GPU, you would normally use [`pagefun`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/pagefun.html "pagefun") for this sort of thing, but I don't think it will work in this situation because of the varying number of equations.